# Finding an app or file?

Tags: macos

I need to install the newest version of Perl on Macbook running Yosemite.  It currently has Perl5.18 built in.  I understand that the system sometimes needs this version and it shouldn't be altered.

I did successfully install the latest version of Perl but I can't find it using Finder or Terminal.  It did not overwrite the 5.18 version but went somewhere else.

How can I locate it?

Thanks

Comment: How did you install it ? MacPort ? Homebrew ?

Comment: What You get when You type `perl` and press "⇥ TAB" twice in Terminal.app ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`locate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/locate.1.html) to see where a Perl binary is installed

```
locate bin\/perl  | grep perl\$
```

for example

```
$ locate bin\/perl  | grep perl\$
/Users/corti/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.20/bin/perl
/Users/corti/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.20t/bin/perl
/opt/local/bin/perl
/usr/bin/perl
```

By the way, I would strongly suggest to use [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl) to install an additional Perl version.